# Qt and C++ to show large DECIMAL number from MySQL without scientific notation

Tags: c++, qt

I have a large value in MySQL.  It is stored in MySQL properly as a DECIMAL(22,2). I  have confirmed that the value is stored properly.  If I run a query via command console I get the proper value back in the desired non-scientific form (the value and the form is: 99996543210987654321.99).

The problem is that when I run the query with Qt/C++ I don't see how I can show the number in non-scientic notation.  I get (9.99965432109877e+19) instead of (99996543210987654321.99).  I want the later.

In C++/Qt This is how I extract the value from the Qt query.
(1) First, I open a database connection to MySQL with Qt.
(2) Then, I make a query to find a specific record. So far so good.
(3) Then, I extract the specific field value from the returned record found by the query using the exact code posted bellow.
*NOTE.  QSqlQuery::value returns a Qvariant.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariant-30

```
if( query3.next() )
{
   QVariant number = query3.value(query3.record().indexOf("account_balance"));
   qout << number.toString() << endl;
}
```

I have also tried (with same result).

```
if( query3.next() )
{    
 qout<<query3.value(query3.record().indexOf("account_balance")).toString()<<endl;
}
```

Just to add, "qout" is just a QTextStream.  I think the problem is not qout because the code bellow outputs 99996543210987654321.99 as is without scientific notation.

```
qout << "99996543210987654321.99" << endl;
```

How can I get back value 99996543210987654321.99 as is without rounding by c++/qt and without scientific notation?

.
.
.
.
.
.

---

**EDIT:**
tried at Pete's suggestion

```
char string_account_balance[32] = "";
sprintf( string_account_balance, "%.2f", query3.value(query3.record().indexOf("account_balance")).toString() );
```

Got errors and crash. Errors:
(1) connot pass objects of non-POD type 'class QByteArray' through '...'; call will abort runtime
(2) format '%.2f' expects type 'double', but argument 3 has type 'int'.

Comment: What type is query3.value returning? If it's a double then the accuracy may already be limited before you convert to a string - 64bit IEE double is only 17digits

Comment: Have you actually tried to read the number from MySQL? If you read it as a string from a C++ program, I think it'll come back the way you want to see it. Remember MySQL will always store it as a string.

Comment: @Pete. yeah, that is what I'm trying to do, I want it returned as a string.  As you can see it is not quite working.  I did try MySQL directly at command console and yes, it gave value back correctly there... but I can't find a way in c++/qt to get it back as a non-scientifically formatted string.

Comment: @martin.That's a good question. I don't know. I believe it is returning a QVariant. In MySQL it is stored as a DECIMAL (which is a "fixed point" SQL data type). It is stored accurately in MySQL as a DECIMAL(22,2). What .value does to this "decimal" data type is something I'm not sure about. As far as I'm concerned it should treat is a string.

Comment: @user... :  Oh, I see, yes. In that case, in my C (not C++) programs I have said something like sprintf( string_account_balance, "%f",  query3.value(query3.record().indexOf("account_balance" )); and that has worked for me.

Comment: @Pete.  I tried that but it doesn't work for 2 reasons and crashes the appl. (COMPILER ERROR 1) cannot pass objects of non-POD type...call will abort at runtime. (COMPILER ERROR 2)
format '%f' expects type 'double', but...  [My COMMENT: of course compiler is correct, my number is not in double compatible form...nor can it ever be].

Comment: Have you seen [Data Types for Qt-supported Database Systems](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/sql-types.html) ?

Comment: @MSalters.  Thanks, I did not see that.  Still I don't see how that would help this particular case.  They don't have DECIMAL for MySQl...most are just mapped to QString anyway.  Even if they did, the problem is I still don't see how to get the value out of QVariant without scientific notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QSqlQuery::value() returns a QVariant, and there is no QVariant::toLongDouble or anything like that (aside from toString(), which doesn't work).  So you have to do the conversion in MySQL--ALTER TABLE with the CHANGE option to change DECIMAL to VARCHAR or something like that, query the result, and then change it back.  Otherwise, looks like you're out of luck, esp. given the link MSalters posted.

Comment: Thanks, though I "hope" your wrong.  I'd hate to store money values as varchar or text in the DB to get around this Qt issue.

Comment: Well, if I'm not, maybe put in a feature request for this for 4.8.  Won't help you in the short term, but I agree it is a significant and surely unnecessary omission from their SQL module.  They could at least send it back as a string.

Comment: I'll give it a few days.  Maybe some hacker can save the day.

Comment: Sorry for bringing this back, it's been 6 years. i guess the hacker did not came. does this answer still hold true?

Answer (score 2):

When investigating about the use of decimal type in Qt in conjunction with MySQL, I found this topic.

I guessed, that the reason of this problem is simple: when Qt reads data from DECIMAL fields, it converts it to double.
So, I took a look at Qt's MySQL driver source, located at QtSDK/QtSources/4.7.4/src/sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.cpp
I found the following lines in qDecodeMYSQLType function:

```
    case FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT :
    case FIELD_TYPE_DOUBLE :
    case FIELD_TYPE_DECIMAL :
#if defined(FIELD_TYPE_NEWDECIMAL)
    case FIELD_TYPE_NEWDECIMAL:
#endif
        type = QVariant::Double;
        break;
```

So, I was right, it handles DECIMAL in the same way, as DOUBLE.

Solution to the problem is simple. Just change this part of code to

```
    case FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT :
    case FIELD_TYPE_DOUBLE :
        type = QVariant::Double;
        break;
    case FIELD_TYPE_DECIMAL :
#if defined(FIELD_TYPE_NEWDECIMAL)
    case FIELD_TYPE_NEWDECIMAL:
#endif
        type = QVariant::String;
        break;
```

and rebuild the MySQL plugin.

My app reads the DECIMAL type correctly now.

Comment: Yes. 
I put in my sample table DECIMAL(22,2) value 99996543210987654321.99, created a QSqlTableModel object in the app and if I call qDebug()<<model->data(model->index(0, 3, QModelIndex())).toString(); I get "99996543210987654321.99"

Answer (score 1):

@user440297 -- I tried (thought I tried) to add this as a comment a couple of hours ago. I guess not.

When I'm faced with this very problem in a C (though not C++) program, the %.nf format specification saves the day. I usually say something like:

```
// instead of:   
//  QVariant number = query3.value(query3.record().indexOf("account_balance"));<br>
// use, approximately:

  char string_account_balance[32] = "";
  sprintf( string_account_balance, %.2f%, query3.value( query3.record().indexOf( "account_balance" ));
```

That should give you all the integral digits you want, a decimal point, and two decimal digits.

Don't change the decimal(22,2) MySQL field. If it's varchar, you'll have to handle all of the arithmetic and ... oh, man, it's too gruesome to think about. In any case, it's an merely output formatting problem, not an internal storage problem or a Qt problem.

I'd always stayed away from the %f format because I thought it *introduced* floating-point format problems; Not so. Instead, it makes floating-point format problems *evaporate.*

-- pete

Comment: ERRORS + CRASH:  (1) connot pass objects of non-POD type 'class QByteArray' through '...'; call will abort runtime

(2) format '%.2f' expects type 'double', but argument 3 has type 'int'.  NOTE: I tried variations of, no luck.  Thanks.

Comment: Then I'd give it a shot with whatever value "QVariant number" ends up being.

Comment: yeah, i did that first.  Same errors and ressult.  Crash.  That's why added .toString() to your suggestion but it did not make things better.  Both compiler complains and appl crashes.  Qvariant is an object not a string... so I don't think sprintf can handle it.

Comment: What was the answer when you asked on the Qt forum? http://www.qtforum.org/index.html?s=ae3ab5f6eb18ffed0da3a3614d9bac90ab8a5832

Answer (score 0):

Qt's probably putting the number in scientific notation because your number is 22 decimal digits long. Doubles can store 53 bits of mantissa, which translates to at most 16 decimal digits (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format).

With that said, maybe you could try a long double, or some other type that can store all 22 decimal digits.

Comment: Right but it shouldn't because DECIMAL in SQL can be 1000 digits long in PostgreSQL and 65 digits long in MySQL.   My measly 22 digits long number should be fine.  DECIMAL is a fixed point data type so Qt shouldn't be dumping my value into a lossy floating point data type like a double behind the scenes. I'm not trying to dump this value into a double, I'm trying to dump it into a string.  There must be a way to extract values from DECIMAL data type fields with Qt.  if not, this is a major bug in Qt.

Comment: Since your record is a QVariant, could you try calling .toString() on it for outputting?